# Call Python functions from C# in Visual Studio Python support VS 2017

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

This is related to new features Visual Studio has introduced - Python support, Machine Learning projects to support.
I have installed support and found that I can create a python project and can run it. However, I could not find how to call a python function from another **C#** file.

Example, I created a classifier.py from given project samples, Now I want to run the classifier and get results from another **C#** class.
If there is no such portability, then how is it different from creating a **C#** Process class object and running the **Python.exe** with our py file as a parameter.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this: exposing WebAPI, exposing commandline and starting a new `Process` from within C#, embedding Python code using IronPython, etc. You're probably after IronPython though. Note that it supports Python 2.x as far as I remember.

Comment: @Asunez: Your suggested methods work but these are are legacy and well proven. I am wondering if Microsoft introduced any developer friendly way to interact these two languages or it is just old icecream in a new cup

Comment: I think you are mistaking two different things. Visual Studio Python Support is just that - it's for working with Python projects inside VS. There is no mention about calling `.py` code from C#. If you could link to some reference about it it would be helpful to progress with the discussion.

Comment: I am not sure if any such portability is promised by MS. If none is seen by anyone else, then this thread can be closed. I hope MS will come with this feature soon. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I was working on integrating C# with Python for my masters thesis until half a year ago and unless nothing new recently popped out I didn't find any other ways easier than the ones I mentioned in my first comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, python support has come in visual studio. Visual studio is supporting running python scripts and debugging. 
However, calling one python function from c# function and vice versa is not supported yet.
Closing the thread. Thanks for suggestions.